# Oracle SQL Developer String variable binding

Tags: sql, string, oracle, variables, binding

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.1.14 and trying to figure out some variable bindings. I started with the queries below:

```
SELECT *
FROM Ships
WHERE UniqueId = 17;
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM Ships
WHERE UniqueId = :variable;
```

These both execute successfully. When you run the second one, Oracle SQL Developer prompts you for a value, of which i enter 17. However, when i try to do the same thing with a string parameter, I am unsuccessful (Query returns 0 rows). For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Ships
WHERE ShipName = 'Atlantic Boat';
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM Ships
WHERE ShipName LIKE :variable;
```

Only the first query is successful. I have tried entering into the popup window

Atlantic Boat

'Atlantic Boat'

"Atlantic Boat"

and other variations without success. How can i make this work?

EDIT: I have tried using the like statement and found some success.

```
SELECT *
FROM Ships
WHERE ShipName LIKE '%Atlantic Boat%';
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM Ships
WHERE ShipName LIKE :variable;
```

Both actually work. The second requires %Atlantic Boat%, with no string quotes (''). I am still unable to get the = one to work however, even with % variations.

Comment: Since it returns 0 rows, are you sure there's this value `Atlantic Boat` in the column `ShipName`?

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear. The third query (ShipName = 'Atlantic Boat') returns the row I am looking for so I am sure it exists. It is only the 4th query which returns 0 rows

Comment: This works fine for me in 4.0.1.14 and 4.0.2.15. You should not have any quotes when you enter the value in the bind window, but the first value you show should have worked. Which *suggests* that isn't quite what you put in; either the case was slightly different, or you had a leading or trailing space, or something like that. Or, perhaps more likely, your field is declares as a `char` rather than a `varchar2`...

Comment: @AlexPoole The column is indeed declared as CHAR(20 CHAR) not a VARCHAR2. Could you explain why it causes the above problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the table is defined with the name as a `varchar2` field then it works as expected:

```
create table ships (uniqueid number, shipname varchar2(20));
insert into ships values (17, 'Atlantic Boat');

SELECT *
FROM Ships
WHERE ShipName = 'Atlantic Boat';

  UNIQUEID SHIPNAME                     
---------- ------------------------------
        17 Atlantic Boat                  

var variable varchar2(20);

anonymous block completed

exec :variable := 'Atlantic Boat';

SELECT *
FROM Ships
WHERE ShipName LIKE :variable;

  UNIQUEID SHIPNAME                     
---------- ------------------------------
        17 Atlantic Boat
```

But if the table has a `char` column then it shows the behaviour you describe:

```
drop table ships;
create table ships (uniqueid number, shipname char(20));
insert into ships values (17, 'Atlantic Boat');

SELECT *
FROM Ships
WHERE ShipName = 'Atlantic Boat';

  UNIQUEID SHIPNAME                     
---------- ------------------------------
        17 Atlantic Boat                  


var variable varchar2(20);
exec :variable := 'Atlantic Boat';

anonymous block completed

SELECT *
FROM Ships
WHERE ShipName LIKE :variable;

no rows selected
```

That happens even if the bind variable is declared as `char(20)` as well.

`char` values are stored blank-padded to the field length, so in this case the stored value is actually `'Atlantic Boat       '`, with 7 spaces at the end. Normally when you do a comparison like `WHERE ShipName = 'Atlantic Boat'` the string literal is [implicitly converted](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF51047) to the column type you are comparing against, and during comparison they are seen as equal. That seems not to be happening for the bind variable, but I can't immediately see any reference to that behaviour in the documentation.

When you use `LIKE 'Atlantic Boat%'` or pass `Atlantic Boat%` as the bind variable, the extra spaces are no longer relevant because the full `'Atlantic Boat       '` is indeed like `Atlantic Boat%`.

There's no real reason to ever use `char` (some like short flags or fields which are always fixed length to be `char`, but even there is makes little difference). The best way to fix this is to change your table definition so the field is `varchar2`.

If you can't do that you can cast the bind variable in the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Ships
WHERE ShipName LIKE cast(:variable as char(20));

  UNIQUEID SHIPNAME                     
---------- ------------------------------
        17 Atlantic Boat
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using SQL Developer 4.0.1.14 and it does work on my side passing only `Atlantic Boat`:

[image]

As @Alex Poole mentioned on his comment above, make sure `ShipName` is of type `varchar2`. Type `desbribe Ships` to check that info:

[image]

---

You can also check [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2852a/6). See that [`like`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) `'Atlantic Boat'` correctly fetches the row.

Comment: which has a different meaning (and possible result) from the original query.

Comment: @njzk2 he said query returns 0 rows. Maybe using the pattern http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp it finds something.